# Post separate messages in RabbitMQ for each element in a list returned by the producer function

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

I trying out spring-cloud-funtions, with RabbitMQ integration. So my producer fetches a list of elements with an IO operation (lets say a database call).
Instead of the list being posted as one single message, I am trying to make make it post a bunch of separate messages to my exchange.
This way my next processor (which consumes from the list) can pick up elements and process them  separately.
My publisher would look something like this:

```
    @Bean
    Supplier<List<Foo>> publisher() {
        return str -> fooDAO.findAll();
    }
```

And I would like my queue to be like:

```
    @Bean
    Consumer<Foo> consumer() {
        return foo -> barDAO.save(foo.getBar());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `StreamBridge` to send each message.

```
streamBridge.send("toStream-out-0", someData);
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources

Answer (score 0):

Above answer provided by Gary works well. Adding one more way to achieve this..ie., by returning a collection of Messages.

```
Collection<Message<Foo>
    @Bean
    Supplier<Collection<Message<Foo>>> publisher() {
        return str -> fooDAO.findAll()
                             .stream()
                             .map(e -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(e).build())
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

[Batch Producers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_batch_producers)

[Spring Cloud Stream - Beyond the Basics:Batch Publishing](https://codelabs.solace.dev/codelabs/spring-cloud-stream-beyond/#6)